# Keep getting a seg fault with my binary search (working in C)

Tags: c, insert, segmentation-fault, binary-tree

I'm having some trouble getting my binary tree to work. One weird thing is when I try to print node data repeatedly, I get a seg fault. I'm taking this as a red flag that I'm doing something wrong. This is a test program I made with just the struct definition and the insertion function. Does anyone notice an issue?

```
   #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <assert.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdbool.h>


    typedef struct Tnode{

        char *name;
        int value;

        struct Tnode *left;
        struct Tnode *right;

    } Tnode;


    Tnode *insert(Tnode *node, char *name, int value){ 

        if(node==NULL){

            Tnode *temp = malloc(sizeof(struct Tnode));

            temp->name = strdup(name);
            temp->value = value;

            temp->left = NULL;
            temp->right = NULL;

            return temp;

        }

        else if(strcmp(name,node->name)<0)
        {
            node->left = insert(node->left, name, value);   
        }

        else if(strcmp(name,node->name)>0)
        {
            node->right = insert(node->right, name, value);
        }   
        else{
            printf("something went wrong\n");
        }   

    }


    int main(){

        Tnode *root = NULL;

        root = insert(root,"george",11);
        root = insert(root,"dick",12);
        root = insert(root,"walter",13);
        root = insert(root,"harry",13);
        printf("%s\n",root->name);  
        root = insert(root,"zink",40);
        printf("%s\n",root->name);  

    }
```

Comment: The code you have here seems to run fine on ideone: https://ideone.com/W1K0Qn

Comment: that's strange. ok. still, shouldn't the output be "george" in both cases, since it's the top node on the tree?

Comment: It would seem that after the insert of zink it is the new root.  You may have other bugs in your code.  You only asked about the segfault.

Comment: sorry, i thought the two were related. Is there any issue with how the insert function is defined that you can see?

Comment: You haven't allocated space for the name string in the Tnode, so when you strdup it to temp->name, you are stomping on stuff.

Comment: A little unrelated, but it would be better to use strncmp instead of strcmp.

Comment: Fred, what syntax do you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "insert" function does not return anything, except in the first `if (node==NULL)` case. When you're not returning something from a function that is supposed to return a value, the behavior is undefined; so you may get a segfault, or it may appear to run on someone else's system, etc.

For all cases besides the `if (node==NULL)` case, you probably want to `return node;`. Or, you may want to `abort()` or `exit()` or something in that "something went wrong" case. You also should `return 0;` from main, but that's not causing your problem.

These issues would be easier to notice if you compile with warnings turned on. With some compilers (e.g. gcc), you can turn on many warnings by passing the -Wall flag to the compiler. I would recommend always compiling with at least -Wall.